# exclude non-duplicated int in vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm new to C++, I came from Swift background, and I'm thankful for your help in advance.

I have a vector that contains int values. Some of them are repeated.
My task here is to get the largest repeated value from the vector.

Example:

```
std::vector<int> myVector;
myVector.push_back(1);
myVector.push_back(8);
myVector.push_back(4);
myVector.push_back(4);
```

I need a function that returns 4 because it's the largest duplicate int in the vector.

Thanks again, and please, if you have any question, please ask it instead of downvoting.

Comment: So you have to use C++ 98? Why?

Comment: Because the grading system is automated and is not accepting c++11

Comment: This is the compiling flags that it's accepting `g++ -pipe -O2 -std=c++14` if it might help

Comment: Then you have full C++11 and more. Where is the problem?

Comment: Is that mean I can compile in c++14?

Comment: If you use that command line you are actually compiling C++14.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151799/discussion-between-mennabah-and-manni66).

Comment: Use a `std::map<int,int>` to count the number of occurences of each value in the vector. And since a map orders its keys, after iterating over the vector simply grab the last key in the map.

Comment: Can you please show an example how to use it with the vector?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Um.. if you key on the value, the last element in the map is the largest key, not the largest count.  Or maybe I missed what you meant. You *can* keep a `largest` key that is updated anytime `++m[value]` exceeds the largest count, also kept, so the concept is still sound.

Comment: @WhozCraig - "largest duplicate int in the vector" != "the int in the vector that's occurs most often".

Comment: "Can you please show an example how to use it with the vector?" -- unfortunately this is stackoverflow.com, and not canyouwritemycodeforme.com. Did you understand what I was suggesting; if not then I can expand my comment; if you did, then what part of this approach are you having a problem doing in C++.

Comment: I'm asking to show an example because I didn't understand it, I think that's obvious. So, as it's stackoverflow.com, you can expand your comment or write a snippet example to elaborate more, not to writemycodeforme.

Comment: I got confused. Do you have access to c++11 or not?

Comment: I do have yes. I should've edited the question. Apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution based only on std algorithms:

1. Sort the list using [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).
2. Iterate backwards over its elements and detect the first one that is equal to its predecessor using [`std::adjacent_find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) and [reverse iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin).

I doubt it gets simpler than this. For your enjoyment:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,7,8};

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    auto result = std::adjacent_find(v.rbegin(), v.rend());

    if(result == v.rend())
        std::cout << "No duplicate elements found.";
    else
        std::cout << "Largest non-unique element: " << *result;
}
```

[Live example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14823b58df79c993).
Properties:

- Zero space overhead if the list can be sorted in place.
- Complexity: O(N log(N)) less than comparisons and K equality comparisons where K is equal to the number of unique elements larger than the one you're after.
- Lines of code making up the algorithm: 2

Comment: Great solution, for a beginner sorting in descending order and using begin, end instead of rbegin, rend might be better.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. It's well explained with a code explanation. Thanks!

Comment: @hakes What does being a beginner have to do with using reverse iterators? If you never read/write code with new concepts, you'll never start learning.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a map, as someone who commented above, and then place the number of appearances of each element of the vector. Afterwards, you take the maximum element via a custom comparator.

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/ZOlNar)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int largestRepeatingNumber(const std::vector<int> & vec)
{
    std::map<int, int> counter;

    std::for_each(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), [&counter] (int elem) {
        counter.find(elem) == counter.end() ? counter[elem] = 1 : ++counter[elem]; });

    return std::max_element(std::begin(counter), std::end(counter), [] (auto lhs, auto rhs) {
         if (lhs.second == rhs.second)
            return lhs.first < rhs.first;
        return lhs.second < rhs.second;
    })->first;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myVector;
    myVector.push_back(1);
    myVector.push_back(8);
    myVector.push_back(4);
    myVector.push_back(4);
    myVector.push_back(3);
    myVector.push_back(3);
    std::cout << largestRepeatingNumber(myVector);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the lower bound and upper bound

so strategy is

1)Sort the original vector (so that can use unique function  on it)

2)find unique  (copy the unique values to a vector so that we can use it to find the values in original vector , not extra search)

3)Find the lower and upper bound value with max distance

for example 1 4 4 8

4 will have max distance

5)Store in map using the count as index (map is ordered so max duplicate value will be at the end )

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{


    std::vector<int> myVector,myvec,counter;
    map<int,int> maxdupe;

    myVector.push_back(1);
    myVector.push_back(8);
    myVector.push_back(4);
    myVector.push_back(4);

    sort(myVector.begin(),myVector.end());
    std::unique_copy(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), std::back_inserter(myvec));
    std::copy(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    cout<<endl;

    for(auto i = myvec.begin(); i!=myvec.end();i++)
    {
    auto lower = std::lower_bound(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), *i);
    auto upper = std::upper_bound(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), *i);
    maxdupe[upper - lower] = *i;
    }

    for(auto i= maxdupe.begin();i!= maxdupe.end();i++)
    {
        cout<<i->first<<i->second<<endl;
    }



  return 0;

}
```

Output

```
1 4 8 
18
24
Program ended with exit code: 0
```